# Raspberry Pi bare metal programming

Tags: operating-system, raspberry-pi, armv6

I have just recently finished an OS internals and design course at school and thought it's about time I start developing my own Operating System (a very simplified one) for an additional Raspberry Pi board I won at a programming contest last month. The class I had was more focused on the theory and had very little attention to the practical thing. So, I guess my question is: Is there a good operating system design book/tutorial I can use to develop a basic Operating System on ARM11?

Comment: that is way too general of a question.  I recommend you take what you have learned in school and ask instead the detailed questions.  How do I do interrupts on my rpi, how do I setup the timer, etc.  The building blocks that you need to bridge the gap between what you did in your class and what you need for the new platform.  github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi has a number of those answers, how to setup a timer, get an interrupt, run a bare metal program, use the mmu, etc.